# How to make toggle-able QAction

Tags: python, pyqt, qaction

Is there a way to make `QAction` stay down after it is clicked. Ideally it could toggle between two states: `On` (down) and `Off` (up)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506201/how-to-add-check-uncheck-qaction-in-the-context-menu

Comment: I'm honestly not having a dig here, but are you on a mission to write all your pyqt code without ever reading any documentation? I'm just curious why you would apparently spend an hour on this, when it would only take you a few minutes at most to consult the [Qt docs for QAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checked-prop) and find all the answers you need. As an added bonus, in this particular case you might also have discovered a better signal to use as well (i.e. `toggled` *vs.* `triggered`).

Comment: Thanks for `toggled` vs `triggered` signal clue! I am not on a mission. I just like Stackoverflow.

Comment: You should like the docs too :) and not expect others to do your (doc-reading) work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a toggle button. This is implemented in Qt via the checkable property: if an action is checkable, then when the action is in a button the button is a toggle button; when the action is in a menu item you see a checkmark; etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
action = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("myicon.png"),"Action Name", None)
action.setCheckable(True)
action.setStatusTip("Tooltip") 
action.setShortcut("Ctrl+D")  
action.triggered.connect(actionTrigged)
```

Comment: you could describe it - to make answer even better.